# Как подключить библиотеку OpenAL к Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Правильно ли я делаю? если нет то как подключить данную библиотеку?
я скачал библиотеку с сайта https://www.openal-soft.org
и в свойствах проекта во вкладке с++ >> общие >> я указал путь в include:
C:\Users\Илюха\Desktop\openal-soft-1.20.1-bin\include
во вкладке комповщик >> общие >> я указал путь к lib:
C:\Users\Илюха\Desktop\openal-soft-1.20.1-bin\libs\Win32
И во вкладке комповщик >> ввод | я ввел слово:
openal32.lib[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `#include <AL/al.h>` и т.д.